# Replace a string using Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to replace a  media query in CSS **text** using c#

I only have the declaration

```
 @media  screen and (min-width:1500px)
```

I also have the new media

```
@media  screen and (min-width:1500px)
{  
 .g{
     border:1px solid red;
   }
}
```

My goal is to replace the old media with the new one using regexr

I manged to make this task here

http://regexr.com/3a58a

using this expression

```
@media\s*screen\sand[\s*]\(min-width:1500px\)([\s,\n,\r]*\{[\s,\n,\r]*.*[\s,\n,\r]*[\s,\n,\r]*.*[\s,\n,\r]*\}*\s*\})
```

but in c# it seem to mark the media and all the roles beneath it,instead of marking only the media.

this is the c# that handle the case

```
  NewCss= Regex.Replace(cssContent, Media_declaration.Replace(" ", "[\\s,\\n,\\r]*").Replace("(", "\\(").Replace(")", "\\)") + @"([\s,\n,\r]*\{[\s,\n,\r]*.*[\s,\n,\r]*[\s,\n,\r]*.*[\s,\n,\r]*\}*\s*\})", new MatchEvaluator(mediaNeVal), RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

where

```
Media_declaration=@media screen and (min-width:1500px)
```

is it possible to mark only the media query using the Media_declaration, so I can replace the Specific text?

Comment: So you want to retain the media line and replace below it `{   .g{     border:1px solid red;   }}` ??

Comment: I would like to replace the media line and below it but replace below it can be a good solution too.

Comment: I am still confused, are you trying to do this?  http://ideone.com/2LKKfL

Comment: it now clear to me that the expression I used isn't right

Comment: I have css file that contain a lot of roles and media queries.I want to replace the specific media inside the text. this media can come in one line or in separate lines and the regex should give solution for all cases.I only have the old media line:&#64; media screen and (min-width:1500px) and the new media vlues:&#64; media screen and (min-width: 1500px) {  .g {font-family: Georgia; }} the new values should replace the old media

Answer (score 0):

The expression you used matches all text up to the last brace because it uses (in two places) the *greedy* `.*`. Use the *non-greedy* `.*?` instead.